# After upgrade to 4.7.29, 500 error on payment

Tags: civicontribute

WI upgraded to 4.7.29 and get this error when on a contribute page. As far as I can see, the file CRM/Core/.php does not exist. What would/should create it?

Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/.php' (include_path='/var/www/slnmembers_drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/:/var/www/slnmembers_drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/packages/:/var/www/slnmembers_drupal/sites/default/files/civicrm/extensions/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/:.:/var/www/slnmembers_drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/var/www/slnmembers_drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:.:/var/www/slnmembers_drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm:/var/www/slnmembers_drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages:/var/www/slnmembers_drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/var/www/slnmembers_drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/var/www/slnmembers_drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/var/www/slnmembers_drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/var/www/slnmembers_drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_sock...\n'

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you've got payment processor configured with an empty class name. Check the tables civicrm_payment_processor and make sure each one has something in the class_name field, e.g. using

```
select id,is_active,class_name from civicrm_payment_processor
```

You can probably delete it if this is the problem.

Comment: Nope. 
`select id,is_active,class_name from civicrm_payment_processor;
+----+-----------+--------------------+
| id | is_active | class_name         |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
|  1 |         0 | Payment_Dummy      |
|  2 |         1 | Payment_Dummy      |
|  5 |         0 | Payment_PayPalImpl |
|  6 |         1 | Payment_PayPalImpl |
|  7 |         1 | Payment_Stripe     |
|  8 |         1 | Payment_Stripe     |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
`

Comment: Which of those processors is enabled on the contribution page? Perhaps the contribution page configuration includes a payment processor id not in the table? Also - you do have the stripe extension installed?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently taking payments via Stripe.  I'll just wait for 4.7.30 and see what happens.